# Delete previous notification(s) using react-native-push-notification

Tags: android, ios, react-native, push-notification

I'm writing an app that sends a local push notification every fifteen minutes while a background timer is running via [`react-native-push-notification`](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification).  If `notification n` isn't acted on by the user, when `notification n+1` is pushed, I'd like to delete `notification n`.

The things I've tried so far are to set `popInitialNotification` to `true` when running `PushNotification.configure()` and setting `ongoing` to `true` when calling `PushNotification.localNotification()`.  I've also tried adding an `id` when calling `localNotification()` and then calling `PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({id: myId})`, but the documentation explicitly says that `cancelLocalNotifications()` only cancels *scheduled* notifications (and I'm pretty sure it means only future ones).

```js
componentWillMount() {
    PushNotification.configure({
        permissions: {
            alert: true,
            badge: true,
            sound: true
        },
        popInitialNotification: true,
    });
}

doPushNotification() {
    if (AppState.currentState !== 'active') {
        PushNotification.localNotification({
            vibration: 500,
            message: 'my message',
            ongoing: true,
        });
    }
}
```

Currently I'm only working on the Android version, but soon I'll work on the iOS version, so a general solution (or the solution for each) would be most helpful.

I'm not totally sold on `react-native-push-notification`, either, if there's a better React Native library out there; I just haven't found one.

### Edit

I figured it out for Android.  Setting the `id` when calling `PushNotification.localNotification()` to the same value as the previous notification will overwrite the notification.

I'm still installing XCode on my Mac, so I can't test the current behavior on iOS just yet.  However, the `react-native-push-notification` readme says that `id` is an Android-only option (as is `ongoing`).  I may still need help getting the iOS notifications to do what I want.

Comment: Their documentation is absolutely terrible indeed. I noticed that there is another library with real docs: https://github.com/wix/react-native-notifications.

Answer (score 4):

The [docs](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification) for react-native-push-notification state that you can cancel a ios local notification using `userInfo` like this:

```
PushNotification.localNotification({
  ...
  userInfo: { id: '123' }
  ...
});
PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({id: '123'});
```

I have tested this, and it works.

For android, this somehow worked:

Creating the notification :

```
 PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
      message: message ,
      date: new Date(date),
      repeatType: "minute",
      id: JSON.stringify(id),
      userInfo: { id: JSON.stringify(id) }
    });

 PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: id});
```

Having the id stringified worked with cancelling the android push notification.

Comment: not only android its working for ios and android both - thank you

Comment: Thats not correct. It's working simply because you have the same value for id both in `id` and `userIndo`. 

On Android if you change the `id` value in the localNotificationSchedule object it will not work.
userInfo does not get filtered.

i.e  PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({ id: id}) is looking for `id` field, not `userInfo.id`

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification#cancelling-notifications

Answer (score 2):

you can add this code inside **handleAppStateChange(appState)**

```
   if (appState === 'active') {
     PushNotification.cancelAllLocalNotifications()
   }
```

Comment: This works if you plan to delete all of them. If not you need to keep track of the id of each notification

Answer (score 1):

if you are useing react-native-push-notification lib.
then you can use this code in componentDidMount section

```
PushNotification.getDeliveredNotifications((all) => {
   console.log(all, "notification liast");
   PushNotification.removeAllDeliveredNotifications();
});
```

here you can get all notification list and clear all list after open your app.
these code work for me in ANDROID device (i did not test it in IOS device)

Answer (score 0):

**Below code works on both iOS and Android** :
We need to stringify id so that it works in android and the date must be created from Date class not from some library like moment.

```
const LocalNotificationSchedule = (id, afterSec, message) => {
   PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({
    id: id+'',
    message: message,
    date: new Date(Date.now() + afterSec * 1000),
    playSound: true,
    soundName: 'default',
    vibrate: true,
    vibration: 300,
    playSound: true,
    soundName: 'default',
    ignoreInForeground: false
  })
}

const CancelLocalNotifications = (id) => {
  PushNotification.cancelLocalNotifications({id: id+''})
}
```

Comment: From Review:  Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what this code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful to the OP as well as other users also with similar issues. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score -2):

Try to delete the notification with [`cancelLocalNotifications`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html#cancellocalnotifications).